# Can we add shadows to (dashed) lines in R (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, visualization

I was asked to add shadows to a dashed-line in R. It would be similar to this image I found on-line, except it is for non-solid lines:

[image: An example line with shadow]

I did not find any specific control/package for this purpose. If it was a solid line that I needed a shadow for, I would have simulated the shadow using another line with different opacity and thickness. But it seems for the non-solid lines (dashed, dotted, etc) this workaround won't work, since their gaps won't match as you change the thickness.

Any ideas?

---

Image is copied from [here](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2007/03/combining-graph-types.html) only for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 4):

You can only tweak this like

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = cumsum(rnorm(20)))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x+0.15, y = y-0.15), alpha = 0.2, lwd = 1.2, linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x+0.15, y = y-0.15), alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1, linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, this workaround won't work for non-solid lines, such  as dashed lines or dotted lines. Or maybe you can do that too?

Comment: Looks not very pretty though and surely does not help to comprehend complex plots.

Comment: This is the problem, specially if you want to keep the shadow very close to the line but with a larger thickness. Are you sure that there is no straight-forward way to add shadow?